# Closing React Semantic UI modal with button and close icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I have a Modal where the user needs to fill in some forms and save whatever was filled in through a button in the Modal. When the user saves I would like the modal to close. I can get this done, through using the `open` prop on the `Modal` component. But if I do this, the modal doesn't close when I attempt to do so through the closeIcon.

What can I do to allow the user to close the Modal through both methods?

Here is my current modal code:

```
  handleCreateButton (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault()
    // ...
    // code to save whatever was typed in the form
    // ...

    this.setState({showModal: false})
  }

  renderModalForm () {
    const {
      something,
      showModal
    } = this.state

    // if I have the open props, I get to close the Modal after the button is clicked
    // however, when using the icon or clicking on dimmer it wont work anymore.
    return (
      <Modal closeIcon closeOnDimmerClick open={showModal} trigger={<Button onClick={() => this.setState({showModal: true})}><Icon className='plus'/>New Challenge</Button>}>
        <Modal.Header>My Modal</Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Content>
          <Form>
            <Form.Input
              label='Something'
              value={something}
              onChange={(evt) => this.handleChangeForms('something', evt.target.value)}
            />
            <Button onClick={(evt) => this.handleCreateButton(evt)}>Save</Button>
          </Form>
        </Modal.Content>
      </Modal>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

when you use the `open` prop you need to use the `onClose` handler prop as well.
By the way, `closeOnDimmerClick` is set to `true` by default.

---

Here is a running example:

```js
const { Modal, Form, Button, Icon } = semanticUIReact;

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      something: '',
      showModal: false
    }
  }

  handleChangeForms = (e, { value }) => {
    this.setState({ something: value });
  }

  handleCreateButton(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault()
    this.closeModal();
  }

  closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({ showModal: false })
  }

  render() {
    const {
      something,
      showModal
    } = this.state

    return (
      <Modal closeIcon onClose={this.closeModal} open={showModal} trigger={<Button onClick={() => this.setState({ showModal: true })}><Icon className='plus' />New Challenge</Button>}>
        <Modal.Header>My Modal</Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Content>
          <Form>
            <Form.Input
              label='Something'
              value={something}
              onChange={this.handleChangeForms}
            />
            <Button onClick={(evt) => this.handleCreateButton(evt)}>Save</Button>
          </Form>
        </Modal.Content>
      </Modal>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.9/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui-react@0.77.1/dist/umd/semantic-ui-react.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```